# How to test more than one variable in an if statement?

Tags: c#, if-statement, variables

I am trying to test more than one variable in an if statement.

```
double firstPlot = RMMA(MultiMA1types.VWMA, 2, 160, 10, 2, 128, 0.75, 0.5).Values[15][0];
double secondPlot = RMMA(MultiMA1types.VWMA, 2, 160, 10, 2, 128, 0.75, 0.5).Values[14][0];
```

In fact their will be more than one variable:
thirdPlot
fourthPlot
…

```
if(firstPlot < highPrice && firstPlot > lowPrice)
```

Is it possible to test each variable in one shot inside the if statement without having to repeat the if statement the same number of times as the number of variables? Like creating one variable that will gather all Plot and be tested all at the same time separately inside the if statement?

Thank you

Comment: Probably, but it's unclear exactly how based on this information alone. It most probably involves using a collection of some sort instead of separate variables. LINQ will allow you to do `.All()` to perform a test against all elements in a collection, for example (and `.Where()` to select matching elements).

Comment: Store the plot instances in a collection and use `Enumerable.All`

Comment: usually where clause are use to distinguish elements from each other.

Comment: `NinjaTrader` and `NinjaScript` tags would be helpful for searches that yield this question.  `C#-5.0` would also be more specific, since the current version of NinjaTrader is limited to that.  I can't add the tags, if somebody with greater rep is willing to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `Values` is a jagged array from which you want to extract the first element of each underlying array, so the following should work:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
...
double[][] plots = RMMA(MultiMA1types.VWMA, 2, 160, 10, 2, 128, 0.75, 0.5).Values;

IEnumerable<double> firstValues = plots.Select(a => a[0]);

bool allValuesInRange = firstValues.All(v => v < highPrice && v > lowPrice);
```

EDIT after your comment:

```
NinjaTrader.NinjaScript.Series<double>[] series = 
    RMMA(MultiMA1types.VWMA, 2, 160, 10, 2, 128, 0.75, 0.5).Values;

IEnumerable<double> firstValues = series.Select(s => s[0]);

foreach (double firstValue in firstValues)
{
    Console.WriteLine(firstValue);
}
```

Comment: error on double[][]: Can not implicitly convert type 'NinjaTrader.NinjaScript.Series <double> []' to 'double' CS0029 93 27

Comment: error on: NinjaScript File Error Code Line Column
SampleDisplayBarsAgo.cs 'NinjaTrader.NinjaScript.Series <double>' does not contain a definition for 'First' and no additional method 'Prime' that accepts a main argument of type 'NinjaTrader.NinjaScript.Series <double>' been found (CSU61) 95 67

Comment: its flashing quite fast in output window an error message i cant catch to print but:its about systemlinq: +Where Selectarray,iterator2 Ninjascript series 1 [systemdouble][double[]double ]  the way i see it your script only test on value in rmma values. not all of them.

Comment: @FrankDuc `firstValues` is an enumerable, you can't print it. See updated code.

Comment: Your code is working Thank you but its not returning or solving my problem. But that part is not your fault. If i Print(firstValue) in the if statement it returns all plots from the RMMA. So it looks like its processing. Good news! But my final variable wont return an answer for each plot. After the if statement result from the plots of the RMMA pass through a bunch of formulas and than a lambda choose the nearest answer from the close price. The variable is call nearclose, i was expecting nearclose to return a result for each plots of the RMMA and its not the case. Where did i do wrong?

Comment: if i test each plot one by one nearclose will return a result for each plot. is it possible to test each plot and keep the result of nearclose for each one independently?

Answer (score 0):

Can you iterate through your array instead? E.g., something like this:

```
    private bool CheckValues(/*params here*/)
    {
        var RMMAVals = RMMA(MultiMA1types.VWMA, 2, 160, 10, 2, 128, 0.75, 0.5);
        for (int k = 0;  k<RMMAVals.Length; k++)
        {
            if (RMMAVals[k][0] >= highPrice || RMMAVals[k][0] <= lowPrice)
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: The RMMA is a tool to create multiple moving average. 2 is the lowest period and 160 the maximum, 10 is an interval, meaning 15 moving averages will be plot in the chart. I would like to test the 9 in the if statement. I created a variable for each one of them firstPlot, secondPlot, … i will try your idea.